# Filter hiearchical data on server-side for select2

Tags: c#, linq

I'm having trouble filtering hierarchical data for a select2 box.

Currently, the select2 gets the hiearchical data from the server and works except for the filtering which I need to implement on the server (ASP.NET MVC).

Sample Data:

```
id   | text           | parentid
----------------------------
0      All              null
1      Headquarters     0
2      1st Floor        1
3      2nd Floor        1
4      Warehouse        0
```

I have the following C# class:

```
public class LocationHierarchy
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<LocationHierarchy> children { get; set; }
    }
```

I get a list of Locations in hierarchical form as follows:

```
IEnumerable<LocationHiearchy> locationsHierarchy = GetLocationHierachy(locations, null);
```

Now I need to filter the list by "searchTerm" where text.contains(searchTerm). The return list should contain all matches and all parents of the matches all the way up to the root, so that the hiearchy of any matches is displayed.

I attempted to filter the results using:

```
locationsHierarchy.Where(c => c.text.Contains(searchTerm));
```

However, that only filters against the top level.

I also tried:

```
.Where((c => c.children.Any(s => s.text.Contains(searchTerm))));
```

but that returns 0 records.

How can I filter the list through the hiearchy and include the parent items for all matches?

Comment: You need to show some sample data to make your question clear. Also show some attempted code you have tried.

Comment: Added sample data and code attempt to clarify.

Comment: Still its not clear, you class consists of `children` but your data show `parentid` what's that? And what you mean by top level? Can you also show the result you're expecting?

Comment: It's a recursive pattern with a self-referencing table to form a hierarchy. "Top Level" refers to the top of the hiearchy (id = 0, text = All in this example). The expected filter on search term, "F" would include records with id: 0, 1, 2, 3; a search for "W" would return records with id: 0 or 4..